# how to insert hyperlink inside a quote with html?

Tags: html

How can I have html tags inside a quote?

Below is the code:

```
'<a target=_blank href=/commands/CancelQuery?query='+Mid(Id,2)+'>Executing</a>'
```

Because it is inside the quotation mark, it could not recognize the tags.
How to I make the word "Executing" hyperlinked? Is there a symbol I can add?

Thanks!

Edit: I'm sorry for the confusion. I don't have much web design knowledge so I didn't fully understand what the code means. Now I see that this is using javascript to reach a database to pull out the information. I'm just going to delete this post now since it's not asking the right question. Thanks for all your replies!

Comment: A string in what language?

Comment: Sorry it's not really a string. It's in the html file.

Comment: There can be a lot more than HTML in an HTML file... can you provide some more surrounding context? It appears that this string is having a query parameter added dynamically somewhere; either with some client-side scripting language or a server side language. There's not enough information in your question to provide an answer.

Comment: you copied this from javascript and wanna stick it in the page now, but you can't becuase of the function call in the middle. there is no answer because we have no idea what you're trying to do.

Comment: Can you expand on how this 'quote' (string?) is being used?

Comment: @XTT: Please edit your question to include more of the surrounding code, it's really hard to understand what you're doing without better context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is HTML it would be completely written wrong it looks like a script string for javascript to use to pull some information from somewhere to finish up the url.

Have you tried:

`"<a target='_blank' href='/commands/CancelQuery?query='" +Mid(Id,2)+ ">Executing</a>"`;

If it is not using javascript to reach a database to pull out the information from "Mid(Id,2)" then I am not sure why you are using a url like that.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="url" target="_blank">Name</a>
```

Change URL with the URL you want it to redirect, and Name with the Name you want the "link" to have. Also if you want to use JavaScript calls, you should include the code so that we can see how to make the code fit the best.

Thanks

Comment: May I ask why the downvote? The other answer may be correct as well. However it does not fit the W3C standards.

Comment: +1 for being the only answer remotely close.. even though it's poorly written and doesn't explain anything..

Comment: I downvoted because IMO it doesn't answer the question. Presumably OP knows how to build a simple link, what's not clear are the intentions and context of the link they have that's preventing it from rendering. Notice the string concatenation, possible client/server function call, etc.

Comment: @Pamblam: you're free to vote how you wish, but do poorly written and non-explanatory answers really add value to a Q&A site?

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ, from what I saw this user does not even know how to create a simple link. Because he mixed JavaScript + the syntax is not exactly as W3C says it has to be.

Comment: i agree cory. there's nothing in the question to indicate op has the slightest clue how to make anchor markup

Comment: "you free to vote how you want... but this is why you shouldn't vote that way.."

Comment: @Pamblam, that´s completely true. When you want to build a house you can´t start with the roof. That´s why I posted a so basic answer trying to 100% fit W3C standards. Because everyone has the right to learn even if this is not the most appropriate way to do it. If he asks IMHO we should give him a proper answer.

Comment: @Pamblam: It was meant more as "I'm not asking you to change your vote, but please think twice about upvoting garbage." This answer still doesn't really answer anything, so *IMO* it doesn't deserve an upvote.

Comment: that's fair, but "garbage" is subjective. i'll stipulate that the answer is not wonderful, but there are plenty of one line answers around here that have lots of votes. *imo* **the value  of the answer is relative to the value of the question**, in this case, the question wasn't worth much.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this is a string being assigned to a JS variable to write HTML on the document. In that case, the HTML tag isn't well formed in your example. This should probably do it.

```
'<a target="_blank" href="/commands/CancelQuery?query=' + Mid(Id,2) + '">Executing</a>';
```

You were missing the quotes from the attribute values of the tag. Also, if you want to really use single quotes inside, you can always escape it using the backslash within the string like so:

```
'<a target=\'_blank\' href=\'/commands/CancelQuery?query='+Mid(Id,2)+'\'>Executing</a>'
```

Comment: except he's not using a script.